# How to open a new window with a button click in python?

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import *
class new1(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(new1, self).__init__()
        loadUi('gui.ui',self)
        self.setWindowTitle("New Window")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked1)
    def clicked1(self):
        loadUi('gui2.ui',self)


app=QApplication(sys.argv)
widget=new1()
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to open "gui2.ui" when pushButton is clicked.This code is not working .Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your Qt designer files to Python files, to do that you can use the command line commands `pyuic5` for ui files and `pyrcc5` for rc files.

To convert ui files to Python:

```
pyuic5 --import-from=widgets -x your_file.ui -o your_file.py
```

To convert rc files to Python:

```
pyrcc5 your_file.rc -o your_file.py
```

Once you have converted the files, don't modify them directly as they can be regenerated if you make changes to the UI, to use them, inherit from them:

```
 class Gui2Dialog(Ui_Gui2, QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        Ui_Gui2.__init__(self)
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Gui 2")

class GuiDialog(Ui_Gui, QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        Ui_Gui.__init__(self)
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("New Window")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked1)

    def clicked1(self):
        gui2_dialog = Gui2Dialog()
        gui2_dialog.exec_()
        gui2_dialog.show()
```